# Google Glass - Autostart Application on Boot

Tags: android, google-glass, android-launcher, autostart, rooted-device

I just received a new google-glass from a company which wants it to support their employees while picking and packing goods in their warehouse. For this reason they need a Server Client application which really isn't the problem.

I never did something with the Glass before and i want to know if it is possible to run a custom Application on boot and to jail the user into it.

Yesterday i rooted the device which gives me full access but i don't know how to go on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible.**

As you have rooted the device, so you can create system app that can be recognised by the reboot event. Rest of the steps are totally similar to android mobile.

**How to do it:**

If you need to know the steps you can search on the web or you can try the following:

**First, you need the permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Also, in your`AndroidManifest.xml`, define your service and listen for the **BOOT_COMPLETED** action:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.MyService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
    android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you need to define the receiver that will get the **BOOT_COMPLETED** action and start your service.

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MySystemService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And now your service should be running when the phone starts up.

Comment: you don't need a rooted device for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED, if you do have a rooted device there are easier ways.